# Efficient calculation of the eigenvector for a 4x4 non-Hermitian matrix

Tags: python, performance, julia, eigenvector

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm (preferred for Julia) to calculate the eigenvectors of a 4x4 non-Hermitian matrix having a structure of

```
a b 0 c
0 0 -1 0
d e 0 f
g h 0 i
```

I know that I can in principle use the build-in function of Julia or python. However, although Julia is mentioned as fast being quite fast, the calculations are a factor 2 slower than if I would use the C++ eigen library (with `fastmath` option). So I’m wondering, which algorithm the `eigen` library is using in this case and if one can be transferred to Julia or Python.

Thanks for any hints and comments

**Update**

Thanks for the comments and not being accurate enough. Here is an example, which works in Julia

```
using BenchmarkTools
using LinearAlgebra
using StaticArrays

function foo(A)
    eigen(A)
    return
end 

function foo2(A)
    @fastmath eigen(A)
    return
end

function foo3(A)
    LinearAlgebra.LAPACK.geevx!('B', 'N', 'V', 'N', copy(A))
    return
end

A = rand(4,4) + im*rand(4,4);
A[:,3] .= 0;
A[2,:] .= 0;
A[2,3] = 1;

AStatic = SMatrix{4,4, ComplexF64}(A)


@benchmark eigen($A)
@benchmark eigen($AStatic)

@benchmark foo($AStatic)
@benchmark foo2($AStatic)
@benchmark foo3($A)
```

*@AboAmmar* Actually I need the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors. The julia version I used, uses *OpenBlas*. However, even using MKL (`MKL.jl`) the performance gain is very small

Also the usage of the fastmath option does not change anything. Maybe, the functions which I'm calling are already compiled so that this option does not work here.

Also the use `StaticArrays` might be useful in some cases. But for non-hermitian matrices the function calls the build-in function of Julia. The QR and LU decomposition can be used, but they will not provide me the eigenvalues. Even `eigenvals()` is not applicable for non-Hermitian matrices

*@Jérôme* Richard thanks for the link to the post. I'm afraid that a manual determinnation, e.g., by using Ferraris method requieres a lot computation and the speed will be the same.

Comment: Some code please, and you should notice that Julia's `eigen(A)` calculates both eigenvalues and eigenvectors unlike some other alternatives. Also, Julia has OpenBLAS and MKL, what exactly did you try?

Comment: Also note that Julia too has a `@fastmath` option; does your comparison include using fastmath in both languages? (Using fastmath has some caveats/potential issues attached to it - in any language - which I hope you're aware of.)

Comment: note that for 4x4, you will get better speed using `StaticArrays`. Blas has a bunch of overhead.

Comment: For small specific matrices like your, it is generally faster to write a code that solve this directly based on the analytical formula (like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72742469)). That being said, the formula start to be pretty big for 4x4 matrices, so BLAS may just be fast enough.

Comment: @AboAmmar I provided an example in Julia. Should I provide also one for C++ and eigen?

Comment: @SundarR fastmath does not work. Maybe the functions are already compiled which I'm calling?

Comment: @OscarSmith Thanks for the hint with StaticArrays. But for non-hermitian matrices there is no implementation which speed up the calculation.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for the link. I'll try it, but I'm afraid that the equations are complex and so the there is no gain. Maybe there exist some mathematical tricks. At least they should exist, becuase eigen++ is quite fast

Comment: @Itzui The example in Julia has a different Matrix structure than explanation text before. Specifically, the third column is zeroed. Is this the case for all the relevant matrices? If so, update the earlier structure, since it should be relevant to faster implementation.

Comment: @DanGetz thanks for mentioning the typo. I made an update of the matrix.

Comment: Note that the sparsity structure of your matrix lets you eliminate a degree of freedom, since we must have `$-v_3 = \lambda v_2$` for an eigenvector `$v$` and eigenvalue `$\lambda$`. Then the remaining components form a 3x3 eigenvector problem, which should be faster than the 4x4 case, especially if you apply the analytic formula as suggested by @JérômeRichard.